# The class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.MulBlankRecord needs to define a clone method, OFBIZ and Apache POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi, ofbiz

complete error message here:

```
The class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.MulBlankRecord needs to define a clone method 
(The class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.MulBlankRecord needs to define a clone method)
```

when trying to use the clone method, i encounter this error. i am using ofbiz and this is part of the implementation that i am required to do.

looking at other forums, it requires me to change the version of poi that i use and i did but i was working on a standalone test application and when i changed the version on that stand alone application, i got the application working.

BUT on this ofbiz application, i changed the version using multiple versions of ofbiz but i still get the same error. the solution that i did on the stand alone application does not seem to work on the ofbiz application

EDIT:

So to summarize, i have two applications, 1 web app (ofbiz) and a standalone one. i use the same library but i get an error for the webapp. i'm just not sure what to do next. i took out the unnecessary libraries on the webapp. and i tried removing the library (then it caused errors because of the missing library then i returned it and it cleared the red lines in eclipse).

i also tried using different versions of poi.jar but i still get the errors. any help or suggestion would be appreciated as i am already out of ideas. the webapp seems to be having problems with the library im not sure what it is but the standalone gets to deal with the actions that i want (cloneSheet())

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What's your code that triggers the error? And are you sure you don't accidentally have multiple copies of POI on your classpath?

Comment: i'm trying to use the sheet i am trying to clone as a template for the other sheets that needs to be created. when you say classpath, does that mean the environment variable classpath? no, i don't have multiple poi libraries set on my classpath. but if your'e referring to a classpath in eclipse, if there is such a thing (i'm not sure), i'll have a check. thanks :D

Comment: thanks for giving me an idea @Gagravarr, on the lib folder there are multiple poi versions and I deleted them and replace them with poi 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the option in eclipse, project > properties > java build path > libraries, do not show the libraries in side the lib folder of an ofbiz component.

so there it is, poi 3.7 just waiting to be deleted., i replaced it with poi 3.9. now the clone Sheet method is now working.